# Instance of the injected service is undefined in Angular 12

Tags: angular, service

Angular Version : 12.0.1

I have created a service for a component, My requirement is to use the service only with this component for now. When I inject the service in the component and try to access its instance it is undefined. For the very first time in the ngOnInit, it is acccessible, but undefined elsewhere.

Relevant code in the component :

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-component',
  templateUrl: './app-component.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app-component.component.scss'],
  providers : [MyService]
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  ...some declarations and initializations
  constructor(private myService: MyService) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.myObservable$ = this.myService?.getSomething('/');
  }


  functionCalledFromTemplaceButtonClick(item : any){

   // The service is undefined here
   return this.myService.getSomething(item);
  }


}
```

Relevant code from the service:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class MyService {
  constructor(
    private httpClient: HttpClient,
  ) {}

  getSomething(item: any) {
   // Makes an api call here
  }
}
```

I have provided the Service - MyService in the module as well.

None of the existing issues helped, Kindly request for some help.

Comment: Probably in ngOnInit it is not accessible as well and you get no error just because it is optional;
Please try to remove providers : [MyService] from @Component
and add import { MyService } from '....';
Does getSomething(item) return something? I don't see any returns in the definition.

Comment: I added a console in the getSomething Fucntion and passed a param from the OnInit and i got the console log printed in the service. But in the functionCalledFromTemplaceButtonClick function the service is undefined.

Comment: GetSomething is suppose to return the observable from the API call but neverthe less the control doesnt even find the instance of the service. So it really doesn't matter what getSomething does right? I believe solving the issue of service instance being undefined should solve the issue. But im not able to figure out what the issue is.

Comment: Can you please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) on an online IDE like [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I removed the method i had and replace it with a arrow function and declared and defined at the top such as below :

```
public functionCalledFromTemplaceButtonClick =(item : any) =>{

   // The service has the context here
   return this.myService.getSomething(item);
  }
```